# git avoid upload files with FTP when merge conflict occured

Tags: php, git, ftp, phpstorm

first, Sorry for my weak english

i have a local repository and a repository on my server which remote to online repository on VSTS.

```
.-local\
        .VSTS
.server/
```

I run pull command in ServerRepo and conflict occured. some files both modified.
so i have tried to edit conflicted file with phpStorm and upload them with FTP.
but upload files Failed!
so i edit non conflicted file and sent it to server with FTP without any issues.

finally i found that just conflicted files cannot be uploaded.

What should I do?

Comment: Solve the conflict, thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i know the reason of this issue.

i use git in server with root user and conflicted file's owner changed to root from admin.

for this reason i recieved error.
i change files owner and issue Solved,